# After Win10 June 21 update, winform webcontrol with Adobe not working anymore

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, pdf, controls

I am using in my Winform appplication (VB, C#) the onboard webcontrol for displaying .pdf documents. Not the optimal solution, but worked fine so far. On the PC, Adobe reader DC is installed.

After the June update on both of my develpment PC's, the Adobe 'Plugin' inside Webcontrol not working anymore. On document load (navigate), it pretends to load but nothing coming up. In addition, with every call, the Adobe services are "hanging" in the task manager. Usually, if I closed my app, all instances disappear. Not anymore now.

I know, the topic was asked over and over again - but is there a simple, easy to use control for Dotnet available which I could use instead of webcontrol/Adobe to display pdf's?

Btw, I tried to deinstall the update. 1st attempt was working, second failed. So this is not the solution

Comment: June update of Win 10 I forgot to add

Comment: You cannot rely on Internet Explorer functionality anymore (it doesn't receive any security updates - or any updates - anymore. Consider it *deprecated*). Use WebView2 instead, it can show PDF content out of the box (no 3rd party plug-ins needed).

Comment: Thanks for that hint ! I tried already using the WebView2 control but I dont know what I am doing wrong, the control doesnt show anything. I started a new test project, put the webview2 on the form and set the source property to "https://www.google.at". Nothing displaying. Any ideas ?

Comment: You probably haven't initialized the WebView2.Core engine. Make the Form.Load handler (or OnLoad method override) `aysnc` and `await [Your WebView2 Instance].EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);`

Comment: Thanks again, still not working. I will open a general request about handling of Webview control an mark this request here as answer.

Comment: Update: got it working. Had to install the Webview2 runtime...